# import different interface based on iOS version

Tags: ios, ios5, preprocessor

I have  created a CustomURLConnection class.

If my version of iOS is greater than 5.0 then I want to use

```
@interface CustomURLConnection : NSURLConnection<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

or else I want to use

```
@interface CustomURLConnection : NSURLConnection
```

How would I go about that?

Comment: What's the difference between both?

Comment: @OhhMee. I have updated the question. Please check it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do these using preprocessor directives:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_5_0 
//Put your ios 5 specific code here
#else
//Put your other code here
#endif
```

Comment: How to check version greater than (>) 5.0 using these preprocessor directives

Comment: This constant will be defined in all versions equal to and greater than 5.  However, as noted below you should be sure this is what you want.  If the functionality only differs slightly you should check at runtime for the version.

Comment: Revisiting this question, I'm not sure this answer is actually correct.  I think this will base this on the compiling SDK version, and not the actual iOS version.  Did this answer work?

Answer (score 2):

The `@interface` is a compile-time construct, that allows the compiler to know that the named symbol is a class type and gives it sufficient information to generate warning messages appropriately based on what appears to be misuse of the class by other actors.

So there's nothing you can do to the `@interface` to make it look different depending on which version of the OS the app is launched on. What would you expect it to do — print out all the compiler warnings you would have received?

In the Objective-C world the best solution is always to build against the latest SDK, to set the lowest iOS version the app is designed for within the Info.plist and to check at runtime (using `NSClassFromString`, `respondsToSelector:`, etc) for any functionality that may be absent as a result.

In your case there should be absolutely no problem just leaving the protocol declarations in there and not thinking twice about it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you building and selling two separate versions of the app?

Preprocessor directives only make sense if you have multiple versions of the app that are compiled separately. If you have one app that needs to behave differently based on the user's iOS version, you will need to do it with runtime checks.